# PHP $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] returns question marks ? for utf-8 characters after the slash

Tags: php, utf-8, request-uri

I have a route.php which gets called for every php request to return a friendly uri.

In route.php it parses $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] to get the parameters. I have a problem now when the request uri contains utf-8 characters after the slash, it will become question marks.

For example this request work well,
http://localhost/route.php/testing

$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] return /route.php/testing

but this does not work,
http://localhost/route.php/良い

$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] return /route.php/??

Is there a way to get the parameters correctly?

Comment: Have you applied proper URL encoding when creating this URL? Or did you simply rely on the browser doing it for you?

Comment: @CBroe The URL is what the user typed in his browser.

Comment: What does the request look like, when you inspect it in your browser dev tools? Mine shows this as `.../%E8%89%AF%E3%81%84`, and in `REQUEST_URI` I am getting that same (encoded) value. `PATH_INFO` shows the decoded version `/良い`. (All in an UTF-8 context.)

Comment: Yes, in my chrome dev network panel it showed Request URL: http://localhost/route.php/%E8%89%AF%E3%81%84 but in php $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] return /route.php/??

Comment: What is the charset of the page in which you are dumping this?

Comment: @CBroe The php page has header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); on top so it should be utf-8.

Comment: @CBroe If I put the url as http://localhost/route.php?良い then $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] will return correctly.

Comment: Can you check what you get in `PATH_INFO` instead of `REQUEST_URI`?

Comment: @CBroe PATH_INFO is not defined here but $_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO'] is defined and the value is exactly the same as REQUEST_URI which is /route.php/??

Answer (score 0):

Try to encode the characters, like so:

`mb_convert_encode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'HTML-ENTITIES','UTF-8');`

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I have tried mb_convert_encoding($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'HTML-ENTITIES','UTF-8') and doesn't work, still return question marks.

Comment: and using `mb_convert_encode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'auto' ,'UTF-8');` ?

Comment: That return error Unknown encoding "auto".

Comment: I tried this and it's not working too. mb_convert_encoding($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], mb_detect_encoding($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), 'UTF-8')